# HTTPS and HttpWebRequest in UWP

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, windows-10-universal

I want to use HTTPS with **HttpWebRequest** in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications and Desktop applications as well. Earlier I was using **ServicePointManager** to manage SSL request but it seems that **ServicePointManager** is not present in UWP. So is there a way which works both in UWP and desktop applications?

Comment: Where is your current `ServicePointManager` code that doesn't work for UWP? I think you should post that

Comment: What UWP version are you targeting? As `ServicePointManager` is part of .NET Standard 2.0, it would work in latest UWP.